Upgrading targetSdk from 34 to 35; necessary to check entire code?
I'm using the newest version of Android Studio on macOS. My app written in Java currently has targetSdk = 34.
When I change it to targetSdk = 35 and Sync Project with Gradle Files I can successfully build and run my app.
But targetSdk = 35 in build.gradle.kts still gives me this message:

It looks like you just edited the targetSdkVersion from 34 to 35 in
the editor. Be sure to consult the documentation on the behaviors that
change as result of this. The Android SDK Upgrade Assistant can help
with safely migrating.

Is this just a standard message or does it mean, there's something wrong with my code? If there're issues with my code, is there a way to make Android Studio show me the relevant code? If this is a standard message, when will it disappear?
BTW: I don't understand why Google is always referring to Android SDK Upgrade Assistant. This isn't an assistant or tool. It has no functionality at all. This is just a documentation. Or am I missing something?

Google documents the behavior changes that will occur when you target a new SDK version: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/15/behavior-changes-15 You need to read that page and see if any of it applies to your app. Regarding the SDK Upgrade Assistant; the message says that it "can help with safely migrating". Have you tried letting it do that and see what happens?

Totally sympathize. What a cluster. No, it's not an error, it's just really adamant that you see it. There used to be a quick fix action that would dismiss it, but now I think you just have to ignore it and build a couple of times and it will go away. And yeah, the Assistant doesn't do anything, AFAICT, so I have no idea how using it is supposed to signal the IDE to dismiss the warning.

This is a standard instructive message from Android Studio once you update the targetSdkVersion. It's meant to remind that with each new API level, there might be changes to system behaviors, permissions, or deprecated APIs that could possibly affect your app.
When you alter targetSdkVersion to 35, Android Studio prompts you to review the Behavior Changes introduced in API 35 (Android 14). It’s not necessarily pointing to any issue with your code; rather, it’s a precautionary message encouraging you to verify that your app is compatible with the new behaviors.
